# Parameter checking in constructor

Tags: java, constructor, typechecking

Suppose I have a constructor for an object that takes about 6 parameters, but two or more of the parameters are related, for example:

```
LoanProduct(CurrencySum maxSum, CurrencySum minSum, Interest interest, etc)
```

**CurrencySum** is a wrapper for two objects: a *BigDecimal* and an *Enum* representing currencies.

**Interest** is an interface with two sublasses: **FixedInterest** and **VariableInterest**.

**VariableInterest** wraps a *BigDecimal* representing a fixed value and an **VarIndex** object that is the varying bit of the interest - VarIndex is basically libor 1m, libor 2m, etc (VariableInterest = BigDecimal fixedValue + VarIndex variableValue)

Now, the bit that annoys me is that when a **LoanProduct** is created, I have to check in the constructor if *maxSum* and *minSum* are of the same **Currency**, and if **VariableInterest** holds a **VarIndex** corresponding to that **Currency**, as  a LoanProduct in euros can't have a VarIndex set for libor, it has to be euribor.

Is there an elegant way to construct the LoanProduct without all this checking ? I'm considering using the builder pattern and make all the checks in the builder, but it still seems ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Builder pattern in my opinion. Effective Java has a good chapter on this.

Or you could encapsulate some of these parameters in their own objects to reduce the number